# Python - Appending list to list during while loop - Result not as expected

Tags: python, list, while-loop

Python/programming newbie here, trying to figure out what is going in with this while loop. First the code:

```
var_list = []
split_string = "pink penguins,green shirts,blue jeans,fried tasty chicken,old-style boots"

def create_variations(split_string):
    init_list = split_string.split(',')
    first_element = init_list[0]

    # change first element of list to prepare for while loop iterations
    popped = init_list.pop()
    added = init_list.insert(0, popped)

    while init_list[0] != first_element:
        popped = init_list.pop()
        added = init_list.insert(0, popped)
        print init_list # prints as expected, with popped element inserted to index[0] on each iteration
        var_list.append(init_list) # keeps appending the same 'init_list' as defined on line 5, not those altered in the loop!

    print var_list

create_variations(split_string)
```

My objective is to create all variations of the `init_list`, meaning that the indexes are rotated so that each index gets to be first just once. These variations are then appended to another list, which is the `var_list` in this code.

However, I am not getting the result I am expecting from the while loop. In the while loop, the piece of code `print init_list` actually prints the variations I want; but the next line of code `var_list.append(init_list)` does not append these variations. Instead the `init_list` as created on line 5 is repeatedly appended to the `var_list`.

What is going on here? And how can I get the different variations of the `init_list` created in the while loop to append to the `var_list`.

Output I expect for `var_list`:

```
[['fried tasty chicken', 'old-style boots', 'pink penguins', 'green shirts', 'blue jeans'],
 ['blue jeans', 'fried tasty chicken', 'old-style boots', 'pink penguins', 'green shirts'],
 ['green shirts', 'blue jeans', 'fried tasty chicken', 'old-style boots', 'pink penguins'],
 ['pink penguins', 'green shirts', 'blue jeans', 'fried tasty chicken', 'old-style boots']]
```

Comment: Could you please provide expected and actual outputs?

Comment: Have a look at [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

Comment: @thefourtheye I added expected output.

Comment: output result is little strange. it missed ['old-style boots', 'pink penguins', 'green shirts', 'blue jeans', 'fried tasty chicken']. it looks wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this line

```
var_list.append(init_list)
```

you are adding a reference to `init_list` everytime. But you need to create a new list. Use this

```
var_list.append(init_list[:])
```

**Explanation**

When you are printing `init_list`, it prints the current state. When you are adding it to `var_list`, you are not adding the current state. You are adding a reference. So, when the actual list changes all references point to the same data.

And you can simplify your program like this

```
def create_variations(split_string):
    init_list = split_string.split(', ')
    for i in range(len(init_list)):
        var_list.append(init_list[:])
        init_list.insert(0, init_list.pop())

    print var_list
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. It still puzzles me a little that `print init_list` in the while loop prints the variations, but `init_list` is not actually changed, thus the `[:]` needs to be added. But now I know that I need to do so while looping.

Comment: when you are printing that, it prints the current state. When you are adding, you are not adding the current state. You are adding a reference. So, when the actual list changes all references point to the same data.

Comment: In Python 3.3+ there is now a `list.copy()` method for this. A little bit clearer syntax that does the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

Here some code that does what I think you want in a simpler fashion :

```
variations = []
items = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(len(items)):
    v = items[i:] + items[:i]
    variations.append(v)

print variations
```

Output :

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 1], [3, 4, 5, 1, 2], [4, 5, 1, 2, 3], [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Or you can use this simple generator :

```
(items[i:] + items[:i] for i in range(len(items)))
```

Comment: Thanks for providing these much nicer pieces of code. I have not used/studied generators yet, now I can go read up on the subject. And all in 1 neat line :-)